# Handling options from multiple Dropdown populated from database using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, html-select, webdriverwait

How to handle drop down field data which comes from database using selenium. A form contains 2 drop down fields and one is having HTML data and it is handled perfectly. Data to the 2nd drop down comes as per the selection from the 1st which comes from database. Need guides to complete the action.

Answer (score 0):

To select from two [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) fields where the data which comes from database using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [java](/questions/tagged/java) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and `selectByVisibleText()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("cssFirstSelectElement")))).selectByVisibleText("firstSelectOptionText");
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("cssSecondSelectElement")))).selectByVisibleText("secondSelectOptionText");
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `selectByValue()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpathFirstSelectElement")))).selectByValue("firstSelectOptionValue");
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpathSecondSelectElement")))).selectByValue("secondSelectOptionValue");
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to select options from 3 interlinked dropdowns with the same class name and different values using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65338836/how-to-select-options-from-3-interlinked-dropdowns-with-the-same-class-name-and/65339401#65339401)